# Embed a rose flower image in 3D space with axes labeled in UTF8

Tags: graphics3d, image, labeling, unicode

I am trying to create an image in which a rose flower image in a 3D space with axes labeled in UTF8! Labels don't render correctly and not sure how to put the image at say the original of XYZ space.

```
Show[Graphics3D@{
    Text[Style[ToString["بوسه", CharacterEncoding ->"UTF8"], Bold, Large, Red, FontFamily -> "Times"], {0, 2, 0}],
    Text[Style[ToString["خنده", CharacterEncoding ->"UTF8"], Bold, Large, Blue, FontFamily -> "Times"], {-2, 0, 0}],
    Text[Style[ToString["پرواز",CharacterEncoding ->"UTF8"], Bold, Large, Purple, FontFamily -> "Times"], {0, 0, 2}]},
PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {0, 2}, {-2, 2}}, AspectRatio -> 1, 
Boxed -> True, Axes -> True, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0}]
```

Also is it possible to have it animated? by rotation or utilizing other images?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

1. You need to use `CharacterEncoding->"Unicode"` to get the Arabic to show up in the text.
2. Use `BoxRatios->1` instead of `AspectRatio->1` to avoid 2D distortion.
3. Use `Texture[rose]` combined with the `VertexTextureCoordinates` of a `Polygon` to get the rose image onto a quad in the 3D graphics. I assume you already have an image like my *"rose.png"*

```
rose = Import["rose.png"];
Show[Graphics3D@{Text[
    Style[ToString["بوسه", CharacterEncoding -> "Unicode"], Bold, 
     Large, Red, FontFamily -> "Times"], {0, 2, 0}], 
   Text[Style[ToString["خنده", CharacterEncoding -> "Unicode"], Bold, 
     Large, Blue, FontFamily -> "Times"], {-2, 0, 0}], 
   Text[Style[ToString["پرواز", CharacterEncoding -> "Unicode"], Bold,
      Large, Purple, FontFamily -> "Times"], {0, 0, 2}],
   EdgeForm[None], Texture[rose], 
    Polygon[{{-1, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 0}, {-1, 1, 0}}, 
    VertexTextureCoordinates -> {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}}]
   }, PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {0, 2}, {-2, 2}}, BoxRatios -> 1, 
 Boxed -> True, Axes -> True, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0}]
```

[image: rose plot]

Animating a rotation is fairly simple too:

```
rose = Import["rose.png"];
frames = Table[
   Graphics3D[{Text[
      Style[ToString["بوسه", CharacterEncoding -> "Unicode"], Bold, 
       Large, Red, FontFamily -> "Times"], {0, 2, 0}], 
     Text[Style[ToString["خنده", CharacterEncoding -> "Unicode"], 
       Bold, Large, Blue, FontFamily -> "Times"], {-2, 0, 0}], 
     Text[Style[ToString["پرواز", CharacterEncoding -> "Unicode"], 
       Bold, Large, Purple, FontFamily -> "Times"], {0, 0, 2}],
     EdgeForm[None], Texture[rose],
     Red, 
     Rotate[Polygon[{{-1, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 0}, {-1, 1, 0}}, 
       VertexTextureCoordinates -> {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}}],
           θ, {0, 1, 0}]
     }, PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {0, 2}, {-2, 2}}, BoxRatios -> 1, 
    Boxed -> True, Axes -> True, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0}, 
    ViewPoint -> {1, -2, 2}]
   , {θ, 0, 2 Pi, 0.05}];
Export["anim.gif", frames, "AnimationRepetitions" -> Infinity]
```

[image: spinning rose animation]

---

I've notified Wolfram of the Arabic left-to-right bug. For the moment, here's a workaround which rasterizes the labels in 2D first:

```
textlabel[str_, colour_] := 
 ColorReplace[
  Rasterize[
   Text[Style[ToString[str, CharacterEncoding -> "Unicode"], Bold, 
     Large, colour, FontFamily -> "Times"]]], White -> Transparent
  ]

rose = Import["rose.png"];
labels = MapThread[textlabel, {{"پرواز","بوسه","خنده"}, {Blue, Red, Purple}}];
frames = Table[
   Graphics3D[{EdgeForm[None], Texture[rose], Red, 
     Rotate[Polygon[{{-1, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 0}, {-1, 1, 0}}, 
       VertexTextureCoordinates -> {{0,0},{1,0},{1,1},{0,1}}], θ, {0,1,0}]},
    AxesLabel -> labels, PlotRange -> {{-2,2},{0,2},{-2,2}}, 
    BoxRatios -> 1, Boxed -> True, Axes -> True, 
    AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0}, ViewPoint -> {1, -2, 2}],
   {θ, 0, 2 Pi, 0.05}];
Export["anim.gif", frames, "AnimationRepetitions" -> Infinity]
```

[image: arabic labels bug workaround]

Comment: I just noticed a bug in Mathematica. If you do `Graphics[{Text[Style[ToString["بوس", CharacterEncoding -> "Unicode"], FontSize -> 70]]}]` then Arabic is written right-to-left which is correct. But if change `Graphics` to `Graphics3D`, it is incorrectly rendered left-to-right.

Comment: Unfortunately. This bug makes the output useless for my presentation.

Comment: @chikitin I've reported it to Wolfram.

Comment: @chikitin I've added a workaround to display Arabic AxesLabels properly by rasterizing the label first.

Comment: Thank you very much. You are great!